DataTable.ToList() raises collection was modified exception
My application modifies certain DataTable from multiple threads. I have already implemented exclusive locking mechanism for adding rows and committing to DB (2 different threads were handling it). Now, UI thread (3rd) uses this table to narrow down data using LINQ and then bind result to Chart control. I have already split it into smallest commands possible to find out where it is happening.
var s1 = dataTable.ToList(); //originally it was dataTable.ToEnumerable()
var s2 = s1.Select(LINQ_expr1);
var s3 = s2.Where(LINQ_expr2);
var s4 = s3.OrderBy(LINQ_expr3);

In all cases it happened while executing the first command. The only 100% working option I can think of right now, would be to include my locking mechanism here. I would like to avoid it, so maybe someone knows solution here? I guess it would have to be something that creates a copy of this variable and is resistant to this exception.
This table can have few hundred thousands rows (it is being truncated regularly, but only after being analysed), that's why I am asking for alternative to my locking solution. It would block other threads, but on the other hand would cost less than DataTable.Copy().

DataTable is not thread safe for modification.  From the docs: This type is safe for multithreaded read operations. You must synchronize any write operations.  That's not entirely well written but it means that you also need to fully synchronize mixtures of reads and writes -- which means locking the reads if a write might happen in a different thread.

Also DataRow is not thread safe for write operations so, unless you project your data rows to DTOs the LINQ queries may return unexpected results if the rows are being modified in another thread.  So, basically, there's no getting around accessing the table inside a lock.

It makes no sense to start with a ToList() since the following LINQ methods do process Enumerables and produce IEnumerable<T>s. It may however be necessary to call ToList() at the end, in order to decouple the chart control from the DataTable and the LINQ query. Otherwise the DataTable may execute the whole query repeatedly.
You are not allowed to modify the DataTable while enumerating it (with ToList() or any another LINQ method). So, make sure that other threads don't modify the DataTable while the query is executing.
It would probably help to put a lock around the query.
lock (myLockObject) {
    var result = dataTable.Rows
        .Where(...)
        .Select(...);
        .OrderBy(...);
}
chart.DataSource = result;

It is important that all threads use the same static lock object when accessing the data table.
private/public static readonly object _lock = new();

Since .NET 9 you can also use the new Lock Object which is slightly more efficient.

It also makes sense to begin with the Where method to narrow down the number of records as soon as possible. There will be less work to be done by the following LINQ methods.
But the question is, whether multi-threading will really speed up things here, since I/O and UI are involved. I/O is often the bottleneck and I/O can't be multi-threaded.

Thanks, I was not aware about lock keyword. I implemented it in all places accessing this datatable and so far, no exception.

It is important that all threads use the same static lock object when accessing the data table. private/public static readonly object _lock = new();

Here are several posts related to your question:

Thread safety for DataTable
Thread-safe List<T> property
Thread Safe Data Access Object C#

First try to use the same data structure across threads to simplify things and avoid dataTable.ToList().
Second when you truncate a list you have to lock it entirely. You could try instead to add a data validity boolean to avoid modifying the list length that would enable you to lock only the data you are removing in the list. You still can truncate now and then, but it is totally suboptimal to lock an entire list just to remove a few elements instead of keeping them.
If a thread often needs to copy the table, it is also more optimal to copy your table once for all at the beginning and use syncronization mechanism.


The only 100% working option I can think of right now, would be to include my locking mechanism here. I would like to avoid it, so maybe someone knows solution here?

If you have multiple threads accessing the object, then all of them need to use the same locking mechanism to access it.
You can get around it, if the object itself is meant to work with multi-threading, but a DataTable is not.
